# Crear un bucle para convertir archivos con obspy

Tags: python-3.x

Tengo 5 archivos en una carpeta (`2009-12-09.EBAN__003, 2009-12-10.EBAN__003, 2009-12-11.EBAN__003, 2009-12-12.EBAN__003, 2009-12-13.EBAN__003`) y los quiero convertir con OBSPY en un nuevo archivo .mseed (`2009-12-09_EBAN__003.mseed, 2009-12-10_EBAN__003.mseed, 2009-12-11_EBAN__003.mseed, 2009-12-12_EBAN__003.mseed, 2009-12-13_EBAN__003.mseed`). Lo consigo con el siguiente script, pero uno a uno.

```
from obspy import read
st = read('2009-12-09.EBAN__003')
print(st)
st.plot()
st.write('2009-12-09_EBAN__003.mseed' , format='MSEED')
```

Me gustaría que me ayudarais a conseguir un bucle que los fuese cambiando uno a uno todos los que se encuentren en la carpeta dónde ejecuto el script. Tengo muchos más archivos que cambiar, esto es solo un ejemplo.

Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Empecemos por escribir tu código en forma de función a la que se le puedan pasar los nombres de los ficheros de entrada y de salida, para que sea genérica y reutilizable:

```
import obspy

def convertir(entrada, salida):
  st = obspy.read(entrada)
  st.write(salida, format="MSEED")
```

Ahora usando la biblioteca `pathlib` hacemos un bucle que itere por todos los ficheros terminados en EBAN__003, y en base a ellos creamos el nombre del fichero de salida (cambiando la extensión) y usamos esos nombres con la función anterior:

```
from pathlib import Path

for f in Path(".").glob("*.EBAN__003"):
  convertir(f, f.with_suffix(".mseed"))
```